# Align labels to left on form using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a login form with labels and input, i can not get the labels to go on the left and input on the right. Currently they are sitting on top of each other. 
Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="login">
    <form name="login" action="submit" method="get" accept- charset="utf-8">


                <label for="usermail">Username</label>
                <input type="email" name="usermail"  placeholder="yourname@email.com" required>


                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>

                <input type="submit" value="Login">


    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
form   {
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width:375px;
height:250px;
font-family: Lucida Sans, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: italic;
line-height: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding:10px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 border: inset 1px solid #333;

 }
 input    { float:right;
 width:350px;
 display:block;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 height: 25px;

 }
```

Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ojz87d0x/

Comment: the width of the form is too small for the labels to align to the left...i increased the width to 475px and the labels were at the left though your styling to the input messed it up a bit

Answer (score 2):

On input, change `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;`, and add the following:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    clear: both;
}
```

You'll also need to make sure that the width of the `input` and the width of the `form` are different enough to allow space for the `label`. In this example [in the fiddle]. I set `input` to `275px` and `form` to `375px`.

Here's a newer [update to your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryanschweitzer/ojz87d0x/2/).

Comment: You should note that you _removed the width_ from the inputs.

Comment: Thanks great, i need the submit button to be full length though its gone small on the right?

Comment: @Assy - sorry, my latest update to the fiddle should fix it. I removed the `width` on `input`, and forgot about it.

Comment: Perfect thanks, i can mess around with the lengths to make it perfect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `input`s are too wide for both the `label`s and `input`s to be next to each other inside the form. So either widen the form or shorten the `input`s.

Next, add `float: left` to the labels.

```css
form {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 375px;
  height: 250px;
  font-family: Lucida Sans, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: inset 1px solid #333;
}
input {
  float: right;
  width: 300px; /*smaller width*/
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 25px;
}
label {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <form name="login" action="submit" method="get" accept- charset="utf-8">


    <label for="usermail">Username</label>
    <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required>


    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Login">


  </form>
</div>
```